# Generating a random number from a vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector, srand

I am testing how to do this before i try and implement it in a larger program that I have to do and an issue is arising. This code works fine but it continues to only give the first number in the vector. What exactly is going wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "time.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int randomNumber;
    int length;
    int i = 0;
    vector<int> x;
    x.push_back(12);
    x.push_back(1);
    x.push_back(6);
    x.push_back(34);
    x.push_back(23);

    srand(time(0));
    length = sizeof(x.capacity() - 1) / sizeof(int);

    while(i < 10){
        randomNumber = x[rand() % length];
        cout << randomNumber << endl;
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you calculate the `length` of your vector is wrong:

```
length = sizeof(x.capacity() - 1) / sizeof(int);
```

since [`capacity()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/capacity/) *returns the size of the storage space currently allocated for the vector, expressed in terms of elements* and thus your `length` is equal to `1` in your example.

You should use [`size()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/size/) instead:

```
length = x.size();
```

Comment: This did the trick I appreciate it! Dividing by sizeof(int) was causing trouble. I appreciate all the help guys.

Answer (score 4):

This call is not right:

`length = sizeof(x.capacity() - 1) / sizeof(int);`

You should use `x.size()` instead to get the size of the vector.

what you do in the above line is - compute the size of `x.capacity() - 1` which is an integer and then divide it by the size of an integer. Thus length is always 1 and so `rand()%length` is always 0.

Comment: Ah! I didn't know about size. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to use `x.size()`, instead of `length`:

```
randomNumber = x[rand() % x.size()];
```